# Place small object inside of big object by angle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, angle

What we have is `angle(0-360)`, our small object is in the `center` and we have `width` and `height` of each object. I have tried to do dividing `widths` and `heights` without success. Task is to place small object in the bottom of the big object, and when big object get rotated we need small object be on the bottom again, but that bottom could be up or left or right, that why i guessed we need the angle.
So basically we need to create circle movement of small object. `Radius` of that circle will be big object `height/2`. But how to calculate X and Y locations from the center to place the small object?
Represantation in images:
Here we have the default state with angle 0 [image]
Here we have angle 47 [image]
And here we have angle 227 [image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem, or what shape the objects are.  Could you add before and after diagrams?

Comment: Indeed, this sort of question needs some graphics to explain it efficiently. Even if it's just hand-drawn in MS Paint.

Comment: i will draw one soon.

Comment: ok, i hope you get the idea.

Comment: The solution really depends on what kind of technique you use for rendering. Does it run in the browser? If so, do you need to use HTML5 canvas?

Comment: The library is fabricJS, but it's generally algorithm which i need to write. We have circle movement of small object, that circle by X and Y away from center i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you want to calculate your new coordinates `r` pixels away from the point `(X,Y)` for an angle `a`. And if your new coordinates would be `(x1, y1)`,

```
x1 = X + r * COS(a)
y1 = Y + r * SIN(a)
```

[Here](http://www.helixsoft.nl/articles/circle/sincos.htm) is some more info and techniques

Comment: Looks good, but small object is a bit in wrong place, in my images it's on the bottom center, but in your algorithm is in middle right.

Comment: This formula is to calculate a circular path related to X,Y coordinates at a radius of r. It is very general purpose.

Comment: After playing with variables i success to do the task. Added 110 to angle :)

Comment: Great! I think you needed to add that because of the starting angle of your rendering.